# Python Automated Login using Requests

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping

I am having a bit of trouble using Python requests to automate login processes for the following site:
https://www.smartmetertexas.com/CAS/public

The intent is to fill and submit the form data before proceeding on to the landing page for web scraping. I am quite new to scraping as well as python so my apologies if there is a glaring mistake here that I have completely overlooked.

I think I have correctly identified the necessary elements in the form (using element id, I hope is the correct answer)

Form:

```
<form action="/pkmslogin.form" method="post" name="Public_index" 
id="Public_index" autocomplete="off"> <input type="password" name="pass_dup" 
style="display:none">
```

Username:

```
<input name="username" autocomplete="off" id="username" tabindex="1" 
value="" type="text" class="txtID" title="You must provide a User ID" 
maxlength="100">
```

Password:

```
<input name="password" autocomplete="off" id="txtPassword" type="password" 
tabindex="2" class="txtPW" title="You must provide a Password" 
maxlength="24">
```

Login Button:

```
<input type="submit" name="logIn" value="Log In" title="Type your User ID, 
Password, and click Log In to access your account" onclick="return 
loginckecks(this.form)">
```

This is the dead simple script for the automated login process:

```
import requests
import sys
import time

USERNAME = 'test1'
PASSWORD = 'password1'

LOGIN_URL = 'https://www.smartmetertexas.com/CAS/public/pkmslogin.form'
PROTECTED_URL = 'https://www.smartmetertexas.com/texas/wps/myportal'

#dict for login
login_data = {
    'username': USERNAME,
    'txtpassword': PASSWORD,
    'submit': 'logIn',
}

with requests.Session() as session:
    #Perform login
    post = session.post(LOGIN_URL, data = login_data)

    #Wait 20 seconds for login to complete
    #time.sleep(15)

    # Print the html
    result = session.get(protected_URL)
    print(result.text)
```

All login attempts fail, and, in addition, the redirected page appears to be different than otherwise presented in a web browser with an incorrect username and password. I would be very grateful for a directed answer pertaining to the specifics of this site.

Comment: Your above pasted elements are of no use. There are around six parameters (noticed using chrome dev tools) in the "Form Data" to be filled in to reach the target page programmatically.

Comment: Would you mind pointing out these parameters specifically? Is this based on the defined methods within function.js? Octoparse appears to do this process flawlessly; however, I would like to perform all of this on my own server and scripts.

Comment: Are you referring to these parameters? : <input type="hidden" name="encode" value="login" /> <input type="hidden" name="id" value="unauthenticated" /> <input type="hidden" name="errorcode" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="errortext" value="" /> <input type="hidden" name="smt_referer" value="none" /> <input type="hidden" name="smt_url" value="/CAS/public/pkmslogin.form" />

Comment: Nope. Do you know how to catch those parameters needed to log in using requests? If you think you can do that by inspecting elements of that page then you are in deep trouble. What you need to do is learn how `dev tools` work? Once you learn that it will not be necessary for you to dig out the elements of that page for `params` or `data`, you can catch it from dev tools very easily. thanks.

Comment: However, if it is possible for you to create a fake credential to get logged in then paste that information here. I will give that a try.

Comment: Just realized I deleted your last comment...sorry. Should I be submitting form information to this instead? https://www.smartmetertexas.com/smt/tPartyAgreementsLogin/public/smt_login.jsp

Comment: Agreed, I am woefully inept at performing this rather simple task at the moment. Could I PM in a manner of your choosing?

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to login using the requests. This piece of code worked for me. I have only used requests module and not selenium. The way you do this is basically by inspecting the headers and the requests browser sends by using the dev tools. I followed [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmf_y8zpOgA) tutorial on youtube to learn about it. I hope you find this helpful. I am also trying to do something similar to you are. So, let me know if you make any progress.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36'
}

login_data = {
    # 'pass_dup': '',
    'username': 'youruser',
    'password': 'password',
    # 'buttonName': '',
    'login-form-type': 'pwd'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.smartmetertexas.com/pkmslogin.form'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)
    print(r.content)
```